# Features total <> Filtered total, geometry problems

Tags: qgis

I have a user who's been adding or editing polygons on a vector layer; he noticed that when he saved the layer that sometimes the polygon would lose its geometry and disappear from the canvas - but the attribute data remained in the table.  He's also received a few 'unable to package..' errors when saving the layer.

I've noticed that in the attribute table, the total number of features is different than the filtered number - but there are no filters applied (see attached screenshot)   I took a look at the records in the .dbf file and the number matches the filtered total, but also includes a completely blank row (no blanks in the attribute table)  We're completely stumped why adding these simple polygon shapes have caused so many issues.

QGIS version 3.6

[image: Features <> Filtered]

Comment: What format is the vector layer? My guess would be it's a geometry validity issue. You can test that by intentionally creating an invalid geometry (eg an hourglass shape where the external boundary crosses over itself).

Comment: It's a MultiPolygon layer.  I did the hourglass shape test and you were correct - it added a record to the attribute table, but there was no geometry.   Our workaround for now, is that we did an export of the layer to Geopackage instead of shapefile, and it now shows the total number of features = the filtered number.

Comment: I had the same problem with a shapefile exported from an ArcGIS file geodatabase. It was a point layer with 6,7 million records and only 4,3 million were visible on the map and attribute table. I have no idea why only 2/3 of the dataset was shown but I suspect limitations of the DBF format. The data was exported for sharing purposes. For now we did a workaround by exporting to CSV (with point coordinates as attributes). I'm still curious of the cause of this problem.

Comment: We have run into a similar problem. Except any new geometries (those with and without geometry errors) disappear (from both the attribute table and the map) on "SAVE". Some previous geometries have also disappeared.